# RxJs reactive map is called twice when once is sufficient

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming, rxjs

In the example below, map is called twice per onNext call which is unnecessary, because the same value for ds can be reused for the two observers. How to write the code such that the map is only called once per onNext call? Or should I use promise?

```
var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(42);

var ds = subject.map(function(x) {
        console.log("processing");
        return x + 100;
});

var subscription1 = ds.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('first observed: ' + x.toString());
    }
);

var subscription2 = ds.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('second observed: ' + x.toString());
    }
);

subject.onNext(56);
subject.onNext(134);
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do that would be to "share" the subscription through the [`share`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observable.md#rxobservableprototypeshare) operator.

This would be the easiest way to do that:

```js
var subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(42);

var ds = subject.map(function(x) {
        console.log("processing");
        return x + 100;
}).share();

var subscription1 = ds.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('first observed: ' + x.toString());
    }
);

var subscription2 = ds.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('second observed: ' + x.toString());
    }
);

subject.onNext(56);
subject.onNext(134);

// => processing
// => first observed: 142
// => processing
// => first observed: 156
// => second observed: 156
// => processing
// => first observed: 234
// => second observed: 234
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know. However, I seriously wonder what design this is that doesn't `share` implicitly - can you help me out there with a quick link?